# Shopware 6, account/login area do dont display

Tags: shopware6

I have create a new Shopware 6 store, but after editing frontend i noticed that clicking on account/login icon in the header, it display a page with only header and footer.
So i can't login as user because nothing is displayed.

any idea? how can i solve this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your producing edits/modifications seems to be the best solution.